# Dynamic Web Project not in eclipse-jee-helios-SR2-win32

Tags: eclipse

I have just installed eclipse helios release 2. But I don't see there is any dynamic web project. this is Eclipse IDE for Java EE Developers I have installed. Is there something missing in this eclipse version. please let me know. it is really needed

Thanks
Manveer

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you're looking in the right spot- a new dynamic web project can be created under "New>Other", then in the dialog selecting "Web>Dynamic Web Project".  If it's not there, then you might want to try re-installing eclipse (you have the right version).